# Elegant Method of Inserting Code Between Loops

Tags: php

In web development, I often find I need to format and print various arrays of data, and separate these blocks of data in some manner.  In other words, I need to be able to insert code *between* each loop, without said code being inserted before the first entry or after the last one.  The most elegant way I've found to accomplish this is as follows:

```
function echoWithBreaks($array){
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
        //Echo an item

        if($i<count($array)-1){
            //Echo "between code"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way that I can see to implement this solution with *foreach* instead of *for*.  Does anyone know of a more elegant solution that will work with *foreach*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [implode][0] function.

Then just echo the imploded string.

---

The only more elegant i can think of making that exact algorithm is this:

```
function implodeEcho($array, $joinValue)
{
   foreach($array as $i => $val)
   {
      if ($i != 0) echo $joinValue;
      echo $val;
   }
}
```

This of course assumes $array only is indexed by integers and not by keys.
[0]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: That would work beautifully if I just needed to insert something between individual words or lines.

I need to separate large blocks of code, however - and imploding large chunks of HTML around a code chunk of indeterminate length sounds very messy.  My apologies if it wasn't clear from the question that I'm working with blocks of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to do that with `foreach`. This is a problem in many languages.

I typically solve this one of two ways:

1. The way you mention above, except with `$i > 0` rather than `$i < count($array) - 1`.
2. Using `join` or [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: Your first solution is quite helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I use sometimes:

```
function echoWithBreaks($array){
    $prefix = '';
    foreach($array as $item){
        echo $prefix;
        //Echo item

        $prefix = '<between code>';
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't!! This works similarly to Wrikken's answer except it does not require an if.

Comment: Whoops.  Sorry - misread.  That's a legit solution - though as I told Wrikken, the initialized variable outside the foreach loop makes me cringe a little.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If more elaborate code then an implode could handle I'd use a simple boolean:

```
$looped = false;
foreach($arr as $var){
    if($looped){
       //do between
    }
    $looped = true;
    //do something with $var
}
```

Comment: I like this answer in theory, and I played with it for a while before posting, but having to define variables outside the loop makes it less clean than using a simple for loop, in my opinion.  Thanks for the input.